# Oracle APEX Join and Count

Tags: sql, join, count, oracle-apex

I have two tables created with SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE 
TicketSales(
    purchase# Number(10),
    client# Integer CONSTRAINT fk1 REFERENCES Customers,
    PRIMARY KEY(purchase#));

CREATE TABLE Customers(
    client# Integer,
    name Char(30),
    Primary Key(client#);
```

Basically table TicketSales holds ticket sales data and client# is foreign key referenced in customers table. I would like to count names that are in TicketSales table. i tried below code with no success:

```
select Count(name)
From Customers 
Where Customers.Client#=TicketSales.Client#
Group by Name;
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a count by each name, then include name in the select and group by clauses

```
select c.Name, Count(*) 
From Customers c 
INNER JOIN TicketSales t ON c.Client# =t.Client#
Group by c.Name;
```

If you want just the count of names, not tickets, then use

```
select Count(*) 
From Customers c 
;
```

Or, for a count of individuals who have tickets recrded against them:

```
select Count(DISTINCT t.Client#) 
From TicketSales t 
;
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much. I can't understand what c and t stands for is this abbreviation from table names. I tried to use left join  before as well and it didn't work, is there any difference between inner and left join?

Comment: Yes. Big difference between those join types.  Many descriptions available.

Comment: Try this for a guide to sql joins. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/visual-representation-of-sql-joins

Comment: By the way it would help other readers if you told us which one of the three queries solves your question. And it would also hekp if you ticked the answer so it marks the question as solved.

Comment: Hey, thank again, i will check guide for sure. This query have helped me: select c.Name, Count(*) 
From Customers c 
INNER JOIN TicketSales t ON c.Client# =t.Client#
Group by c.Name;

Comment: I am sorry for being completely noob, i cant figure out way to close this thread...

Comment: Seems you did. Thanks. There is slways the help link in the footer by the way.